# wxga android layout >600dp

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have an andoid layout which I want to display on tablets and phones.
I've created folders and layouts for 
layout 
layout-land,
layout-sw600dp,
layout-sw600dp-land,
layout-sw720dp,
layout-sw720dp-land,...
For most screens this works ok until I load a 4.7 wxga screen
I understand the relationship between density and size but what am I supposed to do to build a consistent layout when a wxga screen wants to run use the sw720dp layouts ?
If I specify text size based on a dp specific folders xml layout I simply can not get what I want. Am I missing something fundamentally simple . How can I make this layout work on a small screen with high pixel density and a large screen with the same number of pixels?

Here's what it looks like

edit : not enough reputation points to post images ;( post almost pointless now

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know what device is it. Especially its `dp` resolution. If you know it then you can create a `layout-swXXXdp` folder for it. If you don't know then I propose to put something in the layout files and check which is loaded on that device. E.g. in `layout` folder put a `TextView` with text "layout normal", in `layout-sw600dp` put a `TextView` with text "layout sw600dp" and so on. Please note that you can use other numbers as well for the layout folder name like `layout-sw456dp`.

I think in this way you can find the proper layout folder for that device.

Comment: In visual studio ( using xamarin) I'm using a 4.7" wxga, this is the same as a Optimus http://www.phonearena.com/image.php?m=Articles.Images&f=name&id=68693, the issue is if I use androids dpi folders both this 4.7 inch phone uses the same layout folder as a  10.1 inch tablet.

Comment: to clarify : the device uses the sw720dp layout, but so does a 10" tablet